# Getting a 404 not found when trying to call url with postman

Tags: java, maven, jpa, jakarta-ee, ejb

I was working on my old project with maven, trying to implement a rest project, everything worked perfectly , and suddenly, when I tried to recall the url in postman, I keep getting "404 not found".
I don't know what really happened, because everything worked perfectly !!

what I did, is in EJB folder I created three packages 
one for entities
one for the interface 
and the other for the service
then in the webproject I created a package that contains two files, one for the webservice 
and the other for the rest activator !

this is the webservice file :

```
package crm.webservices;

import java.util.List;

import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.ejb.LocalBean;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.DELETE;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.PUT;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.QueryParam;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

import crm.entities.Product;
import crm.impl.ProductImpl;




@Path("products")


public class ProductWs   {

    @EJB
    ProductImpl productImpl;
      private final String status = "{\"status\":\"ok\"}";


    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Path("allproducts")
    public List<Product> getProducts()
    {
        return productImpl.allProducts();
    }
}
```

the second file :

```
package crm.webservices;

import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;

@ApplicationPath("api")
@Stateless
public class RestActivator extends Application {

}
```

I'm new with Maven , and I have no idea what really happened because as I mentioned, eveything was okey.
anyone can help me, I'm stuck here for about 3 hours !!

Comment: Could you add the cURL that you are using?

Comment: http://localhost:9080/projetcrm-web/api/products/allproducts (it was working) I don't know what really happened !

Comment: I think it is not the Maven problem. Because if your Maven doesn't work, it should show that on your IDE/console. The problem may come from the path built by your application. Remember to put '/' in the path in case you need that.

Comment: Solved after creating another new maven project, I guess that my problems were caused by one of the dependencies. thank you .

Answer (score 0):

You have your application path defined as:

```
@ApplicationPath("api")
```

And you're not using it on your cURL, it should be:

```
http://localhost:9080/projetcrm-web/api/products/allproducts
```

Comment: @FirasJERBI you've edited your answer, it said **rest** at the beginning. Is your application running on the port 9080? Is the name **projetcrm-web**? Please, add the console log that you get when you startup your app to your post.

Comment: Yeah when I put localhost:9080 I get the wildfly welcome page

Comment: And the project's name is okay? Do you have any other endpoint to test?

Comment: No, I even deleted the server and created another one, but didn't worked .